# Regular freezes on my Asus Zenbook laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, freeze, asus-laptop

I've been using an ASUS UX310U NotebookPC equipped with W10 for a year. For a few months my PC has randomly freezed for some seconds or has even crashed (blue screen). I've checked my SSD and my HDD with CrystalDiskInfo (status is 'correct' for both my disks). I also use sometimes a Linux live OS on this laptop which never crashes (maybe because it doesn't use my disks?).